# The "file-option" in the git config command

Tags: git

This question is about the documentation rather than the Git itself.

The page https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config lists various forms of the **git config** command:

```
git config [<file-option>] [--type=<type>] [--fixed-value] [--show-origin] [--show-scope] [-z|--null] <name> [<value> [<value-pattern>]]
git config [<file-option>] [--type=<type>] --add <name> <value>
git config [<file-option>] [--type=<type>] [--fixed-value] --replace-all <name> <value> [<value-pattern>]
......
```

Every form contains the `<file-option>` part. But in the text below they never mention it. They speak about the `SCOPE` and `FILE` that look to be it or related. Is that true?

Any idea why they decided to craft their doc in this way?

Comment: Yes, it refers to options like `--system`, `--global`, `--file <filename>`, etc.

Comment: Right. But they should give a full explicit list of those options. What is and what is not. I do not see it there. You are not giving the exact list either. Nevertheless, thanks for your comment.